# Kafka Manager - need to keep track of the users using it for security

Tags: apache-kafka, yahoo-kafka-manager

Need to know if we can find the who has logged on to the Kafka Manager.
It is for security so that can track who accessed the web page.  So  source ip and a request url would be preferred.
How can I get the above info?

Comment: How would kafka know the request url?

Comment: This isn't exactly a kafka (broker) question... And probably depends on the authentication method you're using, and would need to be tracked there

Comment: We need to track who is using the ui of Kafka Manager for security purpose.

Comment: This has nothing to with the broker.All the users of the ui of Kafka Manager we need to track.